# Best settings for a VirtualBox computer to load with malware?

Tags: windows, networking, virtualbox, virtualization, malware

I'm running a Windows 7 host with a Windows XP 64 bit guest machine in VirtualBox. Simply put, I'd like to load it full of malware for recreational purposes. What are the best settings, network or otherwise, to make sure the host is unaffected?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Adapter Network Settings of the VM are set to use **NAT** 
**Don't use shared folders** feature of VirtualBox 
These settings should be good enough as VirtualBox theoretically should **completely isolate** the guest from the host. 
However, tread carefully as advanced malwares ***could*** exploit a programming bug within VirtualBox itself and that can lead to severe security risks for the host (albeit chances of this happening are low)

Comment: Is there any malware that can exploit that virtualization layer and attack host os?

Comment: @Biswa For malware to attack host OS, the malware should be virtualization aware ie. it must know that the user is running it using an emulator or virtualization software. Usually, you won't encounter such malware but there is always a possibility. I don't know of any exploits which specifically target virtualization but you can read this (http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/649219) which contains info on how sometimes a vulnerability in the hardware used can spell disaster.